# Subscript causing later text to become math

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\title{ 
    \begin{huge}
\textbf{Abstract Algebra} 
\end{huge} \\
Finite Field \\
Field Extensions \\
Group Theory
}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{center}
    \LARGE
    \textbf{Finite Field}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \Large
    \textbf{Problems}
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Suppose \textbf{F} is a field with prime subfield \textbf{K}. Prove that any $\sigma \in Aut F$ fixes \textbf{K}.
    \item Suppose \textbf{F} is a field and \textbf{G} is a finite subgroup of 
    $(F^{*},.).$ Prove that \textbf{G} is a cyclic group \ (Hungerford, Page-279).
    \item Suppose \textbf{F} is a finite field. Prove that \textbf{F} is a simple extension of it's prime subfield (Hint :- Use (2)).
    \item Suppose \textbf{F} is a field extension of a finite field \textbf{K}. Prove that \textbf{F} is a simple extension of \textbf{K}.
    \item Suppose \textbf{F} is a finite field. Prove that $|F|=p^{n}$ for some prime $p$ and some $+ve$ integer $n$.
    \item Suppose \textbf{F} is finite field with $p^{n}$ elements where $p$ is a prime and $n$ is a $+ve$ integer. Prove that \textbf{F} is splitting field of  $x^{p^{n}}-x$ over \textbf{Z_p}.
    
    \item  Suppose \textbf{F} is a field with characteristic $p$ and $r\geq 1$ is an integer. Prove that $\phi:F\toF$ defined by $\phi(u)=u^{{p}^{r}}$ is a field homomorphism and \textbf{Z_p} fixing. \\
    Hence prove that if \textbf{F} is finite, then $\phi$ is a \textbf{Z_p} automorphism.

    \item Let $p$ be a prime and $n\geq1$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In item no 7(which is shown in the box and also the picture) when I am using \textbf{Z_p} this then all text are transforming into math text  and the pargraph allingment is disturbed? and also I want to use mathbb with subscript for this \textbf{Z_p} instead of textbf..
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
(note I am using overleaf online tex editor)

Comment: You can't use `_` in normal text. And there is a missing space after `\to`

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, `_` is only allowed in math.  (And you would still have an error with `\toF`, which should be `\to F`.)

At a more fundamental level, you seem to alternate between `\textbf{F}` and `$F$`.  These render differently, which would indicate they are different variables.  As they are math, they should always be in `$`.  If you want different font styles, you could have `\mathbf{F}` or `\mathrm{F}`, but they would still be in `$`.  Since you seem content with `$F$` elsewhere, I'd go with that.

And finally, `{p}^{r}` should just be `p^{r}`.  With `p`, the `{}` aren't bad, but something like `{(a+b)}^{r}` would hide the `)` from TeX, so the spacing before the exponent becomes that of an ordinary math atom, not that of `)`.  So item 7 would end up being:

```tex
\item  Suppose $F$ is a field with characteristic $p$ and $r\geq 1$ is an integer. Prove that $\phi:F\to F$ defined by $\phi(u)=u^{p^{r}}$ is a field homomorphism and $Z_p$ fixing. \\
Hence prove that if $F$ is finite, then $\phi$ is a $Z_p$ automorphism.
```

Item 6 would have similar changes.  If you want `Z_p` to be bold, then you can have `$\mathbf{Z_{p}}$` (but again, decide if you want bold or not, and be consistent).  If you want blackboard bold, you can do `$\mathbb{Z}_{p}$` (there doesn't appear to be a `p` in that font, so we can't do `\mathbb{p}`).  Since `+ve` is an abbreviation for something textual, it should not be in math mode.  But it should probably not be abbreviated to begin with.

Comment: I'd say that `{p}^{r}` *should* be `p^{r}`, although the bad effect is better seen with `(a+b)^r` versus `{(a+b)}^r`.

Comment: In this type \textbf{Z_p} in item no 6 when I am using \mathbb{Z_p} it only shows the symbol of the integer but not the subscript p. help me to solve this problem...

Comment: @ANUVABDAS I added a bit about item 6.

Answer (score 2):

Take your time to read some beginner's manual on LaTeX.

There are several improvements that can be done on your code. The first problem is consistency. Your “F” should *always* be boldface or never. You get consistency if you define a command for the sets you want to have a particular formatting.

Math should *always$ be treated as such. The fact that `\textbf{F}` appears to be the same in print as `\mathbf{F}` should not be a reason for using the former instead of `$\mathbf{F}$` (but hidden in a macro).

Also, if you decide that those special sets should be in boldface, this does not apply to the subscript: so `\mathbf{Z}_{p}` and not `\mathbf{Z_p}`, because “p” stands for a *prime number*.

Check also the other changes I made: I believe you'll learn quite a lot. In particular, you're using hyphens where they shouldn't and not when they should. Note also the ties `~` that avoid possible bad line breaks.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\sset}[1]{% special set
  \mathbf{#1}%
}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

{\huge\bfseries Abstract Algebra \\}
\Large Finite Fields \\
Field Extensions \\
Group Theory
\end{center}

\vspace{6ex}

\begin{center}
\bfseries
{\LARGE Finite Fields \\}
\Large Problems
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Suppose $\sset{F}$ is a field with prime subfield $\sset{K}$.
      Prove that any $\sigma \in \Aut \sset{F}$ fixes $\sset{K}$.

\item Suppose $\sset{F}$ is a field and $\sset{G}$ is a finite subgroup
      of $(\sset{F}^{*},\cdot)$. Prove that $\sset{G}$ is a cyclic
      group. \ (Hungerford, page~279.)

\item Suppose $\sset{F}$ is a finite field. Prove that $\sset{F}$ is a simple
      extension of its prime subfield. (Hint: Use~(2).)

\item Suppose $\sset{F}$ is a field extension of a finite field $\sset{K}$.
      Prove that $\sset{F}$ is a simple extension of $\sset{K}$.

\item Suppose $\sset{F}$ is a finite field. Prove that $|\sset{F}|=p^{n}$
      for some prime~$p$ and some positive integer~$n$.

\item Suppose $\sset{F}$ is finite field with $p^{n}$ elements where $p$~is
      a prime and $n$~is a positive integer. Prove that $\sset{F}$ is
      the splitting field of $x^{p^{n}}-x$ over $\sset{Z}_p$.
    
\item Suppose $\sset{F}$ is a field with characteristic~$p$ and $r\geq 1$
      is an integer. Prove that $\phi\colon \sset{F}\to \sset{F}$ defined by
      $\phi(u)=u^{p^{r}}$ is a field homomorphism and $\sset{Z}_p$ fixing.

      Hence prove that if $\sset{F}$ is finite, then $\phi$ is a
      $\sset{Z}_p$-automorphism.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my document, I have changed \mathbf to \mathbb and I get my desired result. Thanks once again, man.